# How Can I Get user id in Flutter with Firebase Authentication?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I am currently trying to get the user id in Flutter with Firebase authentication, and I am initializing a variable in initState because I want to use that variable later for a Future call to fetch data from Firebase Real-time database with future builder. (This doesn't work because I have to reload the screen each time and then, get the user id).
And here is my code,

```
  final FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  User user;
  String currentUId;
  String currentEmail;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    user = auth.currentUser;
    // Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 5));
    // sleep(Duration(seconds: 5));
    currentUId = user.uid;
    currentEmail = user.email;
    print(currentUId);
}
```

I tried using sleep, but it didn't work, Is there another place where I can put sleep in, that will make the program wait for the user id then run the rest of the program?

Comment: I don't see why it should work. Try `FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid`.

Comment: @Andrej        I still have to hot reload the app in order for the uid to be initialized when I give to a the FutureBuilder. Is there a way I can sleep the program untill uid my variable 'currentUId' is initialized and then continue? I already tried sleep(), and couldn't do it.

Comment: What do you want to do with the uid?

Comment: @Andrej I want the get the uid because I want to fetch data from Firebase Real-time database, and the the key under which I stored those data are based on uid when the user is registered. So now, when I login, I have to get uid first, and then give it to a FutureBuilder to fetch the data from the database based on that specific uid.

Comment: You don't have to wait for it load, you can pass it directly into the `FutureBuilder`.

Comment: I did that too, and I still get this error: The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building Builder:
The getter 'uid' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: uid

Comment: The `FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser` is `null`, you probably don't have a logged in user.

Comment: @Andrej thank you for your answers, I realized that my sign-In method was  Future, so I had to wait for it to finish then get uid. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `auth.currentUser` variable is initialized automatically by Firebase, once it's verified the user's authenticate state. But since verifying the state may require a call to the server, this may not have completed by the time your `currentUId = user.uid` runs.

Instead of trying to wait for the result with sleep calls, I recommend using an auth state listener as shown in the documentation on [handling authentication state](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/usage#authentication-state). This gives you a `Stream<User>`, which you can easily feed into a `StreamBuilder`.

For a longer example, also see: [How to use .currentUser method in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63632366/how-to-use-currentuser-method-in-flutter/63636422#63636422)