# How to not show the Sign In page again if the user is already signed in in Flutter (Dart) and Firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I want to create a Sign in/Log in Page (with Google), but all the tutorials and videos only show how to log in and each time you open the app it asks you to log in. The desired way I want to have it is that If you are already logged in the sign in page shouldn't appear and if you are not signed in or the session has expired then the sign in page should ask you again. Can anyone help with this seeing as it's my first time working with Firebase and the Sign in function.

I have watched around 20 Youtube Videos and tried ChatGPT, but NO video shows you how to not make the page appear again if you are signed in or not. I tried writing an 'if' statement but my code was wonky and didn't work properly. I searched a lot of other places too but it's crazy that no one shows you how to do this -_-. If anyone knows some sort of documentation or a video that does show watchers how to do the desired effect please link it below or please share your code if you have successfully done this before. Much appreciated!

Comment: You can check if you are logged in on the splash screen to jump to the login state, this is my code https://github.com/Daviswww/flutter_ddd_architecture.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How Can I Get user id in Flutter with Firebase Authentication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66940943/how-can-i-get-user-id-in-flutter-with-firebase-authentication)

Answer (score 0):

To have your app respond to the authentication state, you'll want to implement an authentication state listener like the one shown in the first snippet in the Firebase documentation on [getting the current user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/flutter/manage-users#get_a_users_profile).

Instead of calling `listen`, you can set the `authStateChanges()` as the `stream` for a `StreamBuilder` in your widget's `build` method.

Also see:

- [How to use .currentUser method in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63632366/how-to-use-currentuser-method-in-flutter/63636422#63636422) (which includes a full code sample)
- [How Can I Get user id in Flutter with Firebase Authentication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66940943/how-can-i-get-user-id-in-flutter-with-firebase-authentication)