# D/FirebaseAuth(13286): Notifying id token listeners about user

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-authentication

I am trying to sign a user into the login page then return the homepage, every time a run my code it comes with an error message that user is signed in but is not returning the signed in user to the homepage.
Here below is some of my code, some parts are mostly the functionality and not the UI

homepage:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

 class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
 }

 class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!;

 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Text('User signed in'),
```

error

> I/FirebaseAuth(13286): Logging in as test@gmail.com with empty reCAPTCHA token
> 2
> W/System  (13286): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its  value was null.
> D/FirebaseAuth(13286): Notifying id token listeners about user (
> gWbF8CfrhthiL7YrjszqDDnaI462 ).

login

```
class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
//Txt Controllers
final _emailController = TextEditingController();
final _passwordController = TextEditingController();

//methods
 Future signIn() async {
 try {
  await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
      email: _emailController.text.trim(),
      password: _passwordController.text.trim());
    
  } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
   if (e.code == 'user-not-found') {
    print('No existing User');
  } else if (e.code == 'wrong-password') {
    print('Wrong password');
```

main

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:yuhikexxx/login_page.dart';
import 'package:yuhikexxx/home_page.dart';

 class MainPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MainPage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
    body: StreamBuilder<User?>(
    stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasData) {
        return HomePage();
          } else {
            return const LoginPage();
          }
        },
      ),
    );
}
 }
```

Main dart file

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:yuhikexxx/firebase_options.dart';
import 'package:yuhikexxx/login_page.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
          theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: 
 Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: const LoginPage(),
    );
  }
}
```

The phone is connected to internet properly.
I wrote this line on manifestxml inside application.
The password has 6 characters in length.
Email/Password Sign-in method on firebase console is enabled.

Comment: On Stack Overflow, please [don't show pictures of text and code](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/formatting-text-code#dont-use-screenshots-of-text). Copy the text into the question itself and format it so that it's easy to read, copy, and search. You can edit the question to correct this using the edit link at the bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the app to respond to the user signing in, you'll want to listen to the `authStateChanges()` stream as shown in the first code snippet in the documentation on [getting the current user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/flutter/manage-users#get_a_users_profile). Easiest is to use this `authStateChanges()` stream  in a `StreamBuilder` widget in your UI.

Also see:

- [Firebase Login with Flutter using onAuthStateChanged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45353730/firebase-login-with-flutter-using-onauthstatechanged)
- [How to not show the Sign In page again if the user is already signed in in Flutter (Dart) and Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75420086/how-to-not-show-the-sign-in-page-again-if-the-user-is-already-signed-in-in-flutt)

Comment: Thank you ive done that, and it works now :)